# What is the proximal mapping of the function $f(x)=-\min(\frac{\gamma x^2}{2},\tau)$

Tags: optimization, continuity

I try to calculate the proximal mapping of the function $f(x)=-\min(\frac{\gamma x^2}{2},\tau)$, 
where x is a vector of length $d$, $\gamma\geq 1$ and $\rho>\gamma$.

So, looking at the problem in one dimension
$$
prox_{\frac{\rho-\gamma}{\gamma\rho}f}(y)=arg\min_x -\min(\frac{\gamma x^2}{2},\tau)+\frac{\gamma\rho}{2(\rho-\gamma)}(x-y)^2
$$
I divide it into two different cases:

If $|x|\leq \sqrt{\frac{2 \tau}{\gamma}}$

$$
arg\min_x -\frac{\gamma x^2}{2}+\frac{\gamma\rho}{2(\rho-\gamma)}(x-y)^2
$$

I differentiate the above problem with respect to x  to find a stationary point and it yields
$$
x=\frac{\rho}{\gamma}y
$$

If $|x|\geq \sqrt{\frac{2 \tau}{\gamma}}$ I have 
$$
arg\min_x -\tau +\frac{\gamma\rho}{2(\rho-\gamma)}(x-y)^2
$$

Which yields 
$$
x=y
$$

Therfore, my proximal mapping of the function is 
$$
prox_{\frac{\rho-\gamma}{\gamma\rho}f}(y) =\begin{cases} \frac{\rho}{\gamma}y \text{ if } |y|\leq \sqrt{\frac{2 \tau \gamma}{\rho^2}}\\
y \text{ if } |y|\geq \sqrt{\frac{2 \tau }{\gamma}}
\end{cases}
$$

However, if I have $\sqrt{\frac{2 \tau }{\gamma}}\geq|y|\geq \sqrt{\frac{2 \tau \gamma}{\rho^2}}$ I do not have any solution. I know that the optimal solution in that case is $\sqrt{\frac{2 \tau }{\gamma}}$, but how do I prove it? And where did I go wrong in my calculations?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of $x=\frac{\rho}{\gamma}y$ I think it should be $x=\frac{\rho}{2\rho-\gamma}y$. Please check!

Comment: Thank you, I wrote my denominate wrongly. I will correct this. And here is how i differentiate, I have:
$-\gamma x +\frac{\gamma \rho}{\rho - \gamma} (x-y)=0$ I multiply with $\rho-\gamma$ on both sides and dived by $\gamma$.   I have then $\gamma x - \rho x + \rho x - \rho y =0$ Which yields $x=\frac{\rho}{\gamma}y$